# Подзапрос не возвращает данных

Tags: sql, база-данных, oracle

Есть запрос:

```
    
select  * from ( 
          select t.zakaz_sap zakaz, t.sklad_c skladc 
          from   mnt_nakl_out t 
          where  substr(t.zakaz_sap,1,1) = 'R' 
                 and substr(t.zakaz_sap,11,2) != '00' 
                 and nvl(t.processed_sap,0) = 2 
                 and t.zex_c = 31 
                 and t.priz_au ||'`'||t.priz_gp not in ('1`1','3`1') 
                 and trunc(t.date_doc,'mm') = '01.11.2017' 
         
 union all 
          select t.zakaz_sap1 zakaz, t.sklad_c skladc 
          from   mnt_nakl_out t 
          where  substr(t.zakaz_sap1,1,1) = 'R' 
                 and substr(t.zakaz_sap,11,2) != '00' 
                 and nvl(t.processed_sap,0) = 2 
                 and t.zex_c = 31 
                 and t.priz_au ||'`'||t.priz_gp not in ('1`1','3`1') 
                 and trunc(t.date_doc,'mm') = '01.11.2017')
```

Суть в том, что данный запрос не возвращает данных. Если убираю запрос из подзапроса и привожу к виду:

```
select t.zakaz_sap zakaz, t.sklad_c skladc 
              from   mnt_nakl_out t 
              where  substr(t.zakaz_sap,1,1) = 'R' 
                     and substr(t.zakaz_sap,11,2) != '00' 
                     and nvl(t.processed_sap,0) = 2 
                     and t.zex_c = 31 
                     and t.priz_au ||'`'||t.priz_gp not in ('1`1','3`1') 
                     and trunc(t.date_doc,'mm') = '01.11.2017' 
             
     union all 
              select t.zakaz_sap1 zakaz, t.sklad_c skladc 
              from   mnt_nakl_out t 
              where  substr(t.zakaz_sap1,1,1) = 'R' 
                     and substr(t.zakaz_sap,11,2) != '00' 
                     and nvl(t.processed_sap,0) = 2 
                     and t.zex_c = 31 
                     and t.priz_au ||'`'||t.priz_gp not in ('1`1','3`1') 
                     and trunc(t.date_doc,'mm') = '01.11.2017'
```

Данный возвращаются корректно. Т.е. элементарно убираю "select * from" и все начинает работать корректно. Как привести первоначальный запрос к виду, чтобы он возвращал данные? Необходимо для последующего использования групповых функций.

Comment: не возвращает данные - это возвращает 0 строк?

Comment: Да, все верно, столбцы при этом есть.

Comment: Запросы идентичные. По этому ваш вопрос звучит как какая то магия. Если просто скопировать запрос без `select * from` и дописать к нему их, точно данные перестают возвращаться?

Comment: Дурацкие предположения, которые возможно помогут решить вашу проблему. Убедитесь, что вы их выполняете на одной и той же БД, под одним и тем же пользователем. И что вы выполняете именно их ;)

Comment: Добавьте to_char в сравнения с литералом (ну, или наоборот, to_date с другой стороны). А то это потом может вылезти боком.

Comment: Будьте уверены, маразм крепчал еще не настолько. Селекты выполняются из одной и той же БД и пользователя. При необходимости сброшу вам скриншоты, посмеемся. 
Баг plsql developer?

Comment: Я как то дошел до СО с вопросом, почему грант не работает. Разные БД селектил и грантовал.

Comment: Вообще я видел ситуацию, когда Plsql developer не отрисовывал результаты. В качестве эксперемента замените `select * from` на `select count(1)`

Comment: И вопрос, который должен был следовать первым. Компьютер перезагружали?

Comment: Самое смешное, что в функции, откуда селект был "извлечен" эта конструкция выполняется. Аштрисёт

Comment: что значит "в функции" ?

Comment: может алиас дать для подзапроса? когда-то был такой баг

Comment: @SergeNazarenko, а алиасом та же песня

Comment: Как тут создать чат уже?)

Comment: @Viktorov должно появиться предложение, но эта функция последнее время болеет )

Comment: А вообще. Добавьте в вопрос скриншоты выполнения обоих запросов. Желательно в одном окне. И так, чтобы параноик во мне видел имя и пользователя БД в которой они выполняются)

Comment: Конструкция `trunc(t.date_doc,'mm') = '01.11.2017'` в любой момент времени может как работать так и не работать. trunc() от даты возвращает поле типа date. А сравнивать date со строкой в таком формате нельзя, потому что зависит от региональных настроек соединения. для начала поменяйте это условие на `t.date_doc>=DATE'2017-11-01' and t.date_doc < DATE'2017-12-01'` если после этого чудеса не исчезнут, то тогда это действительно чудеса и надо будет посмотреть планы выполнения обоих вариантов

Comment: Тут надо просто сокращать запрос до минимума , пока чудеса не исчезнуть. Или попробовать в другом клиенте, например в sqlplus.

Comment: Еще один вариант танца с бубном. Укажите разные алиасы. Вместо t укажите t1 и t2